# Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 LTS - Can I easily connect to a new wired network like I could during setup?

Tags: networking, server, internet, ethernet

During the installation of Ubuntu Server, my wired network is automatically detected and connected. This is super convenient for first-time setup, so is there a way to re-run that automatic detection later on, if I were to move my server to a different network?

Everything I found elsewhere guided me through a long and tedious process of manually adding or editing the network configuration, when, theoretically, I should be able to redo what was done initially.

I fully expected my server to connect to a new network after being moved and plugged in, but nothing I tried seemed to even recognize that I had Ethernet connected. Yet, when booting up the live installer, my network was detected in just a few seconds.

I hadn't changed anything within the OS nearly at all, having only installed it a day earlier, so this has me a bit stumped. Is manual re-setup the only way to go?

I wound up reinstalling the OS and using the setup's auto-detection to get the new network set up, but I'd like to avoid yet another reinstall should I choose to move the system back to its original network.

Comment: Presumably you are using Netplan. https://netplan.io/examples/ It shouldn’t be difficult to adjust the `/etc/netplan/config.yaml` file. Just remember you have to run `sudo netplan apply` to apply the changes